# Passar variáveis de erro entre dois ficheiros php

Tags: php, formulário, variáveis

Olá

Estou a tentar fazer a validação de um formulário em diferentes ficheiros, mas não consigo passar as mensagens de erro entre eles.

Em **index.php** tenho o código do formulário :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Great Train Journeys</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-    scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li> 

            <li>
                <a href="#">destinations</a>
                <div>    
                <div class="nav-column">                        
                    <h3>uk & ireland</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">England</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Ireland</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Scotland</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Wales</a> </li>
                    </ul>


                    <h3>mainland europe</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Austria</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Belgium</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Bosnia & Herzegovina</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Bulgaria</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Croatia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Czech Republic</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Denmark</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Estonia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Finland</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">France</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Germany</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Greece</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Hungary</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Italy</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Latvia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Lithuania</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Luxembourg</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3>mainland europe cont...</h3>
                    <ul>                                                                                                               
                        <li> <a href="#">Macedonia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Montenegro</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Norway</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Poland</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Portugal</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Roménia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Russia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Serbia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Slovakia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Slovenia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Spain</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Sweden</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Switzerland</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">The Netherlands</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Turkey</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Ukraine</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                     <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3>north america</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Alaska</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Canada</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Mexico</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">United States</a> </li>
                    </ul>                     

                    <h3>central america</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Guatemala</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Costa Rica</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Cuba</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Panama</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">St Kitts and Nevis</a> </li>
                    </ul>                 

                    <h3>south america</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Argentina</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Brazil</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Bolívia</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Chile</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Colombia</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Ecuador</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Paraguay</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Peru</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Uruguay</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Venezuela</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 

                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3>africa</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Egypt</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Morocco</a> </li>                                                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Namibia</a></li>                            
                        <li> <a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Tunisia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Tanzania</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Zambia</a></li>
                    </ul>                        
                </div>

                  <div class="nav-column">
                     <h3>asia</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Bangladesh</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Cambodia</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">China</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">India</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Indonesia</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Japan</a></li> 
                        <li> <a href="#">Laos</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Myanmar</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Nepal</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Singapore</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Thailand</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Tanzania</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Uzbekistan</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Vietnam</a> </li>

                    </ul>                                 

                    <h3>oceania</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Australia</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">New Zealand</a> </li>                                                        

                    </ul>
                </div>

                </div>   
            </li>

            <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>         
</div>


    <section id="galeria">
        <img class="slider fade" src="images/Flam Railway_small.jpg" alt=""/>
        <img class="slider fade" src="images/rocky-mountaineer.jpg" alt="" title="Rocky Mountaineer"/>
        <img class="slider fade" src="images/Hogwarts train.png" alt=""/>
        <img class="slider fade" src="images/amtrak-starlight_small.jpg" alt=""/>
        <img class="slider fade" src="images/hiram_bingham_720.jpg" alt=""/>
        <img class="slider fade" src="images/rovos rail.jpg" alt=""/>
        <img class="slider fade" src="images/Venice Simplon.jpg" alt=""/>
        <img class="slider fade" src="images/the ghan.jpg" alt=""/>

        <span id="prev">&laquo;</span>
        <span id="next">&raquo;</span>
    </section>      

    <section id="about">            

        <br>            
        <div id="aboutArticle">
        <h3>Discover the world's greatest train journeys</h3>                
        <p id="p1">                
            Ever wondered where a train can take you, besides getting you to your workplace (if that's the case) ? <br><br>
            There is another side of the story...across our beloved planet Earth, several trains meander through
            viaducts, rivers, tunnels, glaciers and fjords, where beauty meets the eye. <br><br>
            Several scenic train journeys can be found in every continent and that's what this site is all about...to showcase
            every journey with a detailed description about it's points of interest, what to expect, what to see and guide
            you through the magnificent views you will come across while looking through the window...<br><br> 

            So, why not take a vacation in Switzerland and get on the Glacier Express? <br>
            Or cross Asia in the Trans-Siberian train? <br>
            Ever heard of the Blue train or the Rovos rail, two magnificent african journeys? <br>
            Or even the Flam Railway in Norway?<br><br>

            Get on board and discover what a scenic train journey can offer you...the possibility to travel
            several miles, while watching the beautiful landscapes go by. <br><br>
            There's no other form of transportation that can offer travelling through majestic, inaccessible places.
            <br>                
        </p>            
        </div>            
    </section>

    <br>
    <br>

    <section id="contact">          
        <div id="contactForm">
            <h3>Contact Us</h3>
            <p>
                If you wish to contact us about linking your site, copyright issues, feedback, errors on the website or any 
                other issue, please send us a message using the form below.<br>
                We appreciate your contact in helping us improve your navigation experience. 
            </p>


            <form id="form" name="contactForm" method="post" action="php/form.php">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Your name</label> 
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="40" placeholder="Write your Name"  >
                <span class="error"><?php echo $nameError;  ?></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Your email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="user_mail" placeholder="email@example.com">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $emailError;  ?></span> 
            </div>                
            <div>
                <label for="topic">Select Topic</label>
                <select id="topic" name="topic">
                    <option selected disabled hidden value="">Choose a Topic</option>
                    <option value="link">Site Link</option>
                    <option value="copyright">Copyright</option>
                    <option value="errors">Site/Article errors</option>
                    <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $topicError;  ?></span>
            </div>                
            <div>
                <label for="msg">Your message</label>
                <textarea id="msg" name="user_message" placeholder="Write your message"></textarea>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $msgError;  ?></span>
            </div>                
            <div class="button">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  value="true">Submit</button> 
                <span class="success"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>            
    </section>

    <section id="footer">
        <p>
        O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. 
        O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias 
        desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para
        criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos,
        mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se
        essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização
        das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais
        recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que
        incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </section>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

E em **form.php** faço a validação dos inputs e a inserção na base de dados usando prepared statements. Acontece que as variáveis de erro $nameError, $emailError, $topicError e $msgError em index.php, não mostram as mensagens ao utilizador. A única mensagem que aparece é que estas variáveis não estão definidas mas isso é fácil de resolver declarando-as em index.php mas não é isso que pretendo, pois consigo desta forma anular o erro de "undefined variable" embora sem fazer a validação dos campos do formulário.

Eis o codigo de **form.php**

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "site_comboios";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['user_mail'];
$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$msg = $_POST['user_message'];

$nameError = "";
$emailError = "";
$topicError = "";
$msgError = "";

if( !empty( $_POST['submit'])) {
if(empty( $name) || !isset($name) ) {
    $nameError = "Name is required" ;
}

if(empty( $email) || !isset($email)) {
    $emailError = "Email is required";
} elseif(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailError = "Please insert a correct email address";  
}  

if(empty( $topic) || !isset($topic) ) {
    $topicError = "Please choose a topic";
} 

if(empty( $msg) || !isset($msg) ) {
    $msgError = "Let us know your opinion";
}
}

//Create connection to database
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//check connection
if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo 'Error connecting to database';
}

//Prepared Statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO contacts(Nome, Email, Topico,   Mensagem)  VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)" );
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $name, $email, $topic, $msg);
$stmt->execute();
```

Já experimentei usar a superglobal $_SESSION para passar variáveis mas não resultou.

Que método posso usar para fazer esta validação do formulário?

Comment: usou a session assim ? $_SESSION['erro'] = 'mensagem de erro'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alguns problemas encontrado:**

- O `action` do seu formulário está apontando para outro arquivo, desta forma, o PHP deixao arquivo `index.php` e chama o arquivo `php/form.php`, sendo que esse último não contém o formulário, então não exibiria as mensagens:

  ```
  action="php/form.php"
  ```

  Alterei para um valor em branco, isso quer dizer que quando postar o formulário, os dados serão postados para o arquivo `index.php` novamente, uma vez que este contém o formulário.

  ```
  action=""
  ```

  Dessa forma, não haverá erro, porém nada será processado, pois você ainda não fez o `INCLUDE/REQUIRE` para o arquivo formulário.
- Fazer `REQUIRE/INCLUDE` para o formulário:

  Se os arquivos `index.php` e `form.php` estiverem na mesma pasta, simplesmente adiciona a linha no arquivo `index.php`:

  `<?php require_once 'form.php'; ?>`

  Se os arquivos `index.php` e `form.php` **NÃO** estiverem na mesma pasta, adiciona a linha no arquivo `index.php`, INFORMANDO A PASTA EM QUE ESTÁ O ARQUIVO `form.php`, exemplo, se o arquivo `form.php` estiver na pasta `php`, que está dentro da pasta onde está localizado o arquivo `index.php`:

  `<?php require_once './php/form.php'; ?>`
- Ajustar o arquivo `form.php` para somente consultar o valor do array `$_POST` e só conectar ao banco de dados se o formulário tiver sido postado (veja arquivo postado abaixo).
- Ajustar o arquivo `index.php` para exibir as mensagens de erro e manter os valores dos campos que não tiverem erro (veja arquivo postado abaixo).
- A validação do e-mail estava incorreta:

  ```
  } elseif (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailError = "Please insert a correct email address";
  }
  ```

  Para indicar um erro no e-mail, o teste deveria ser:

  ```
  (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
  ```

  ou

  ```
  (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  ```

**Abaixo os arquivos corrigidos, considerando que os dois estejam na mesma pasta (caso não estejam, será necessário alterar o caminho em `require_once`):**

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Great Train Journeys</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-    scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li> 

                <li>
                    <a href="#">destinations</a>
                    <div>    
                        <div class="nav-column">                        
                            <h3>uk & ireland</h3>

                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#">England</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Ireland</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Scotland</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Wales</a> </li>
                            </ul>


                            <h3>mainland europe</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#">Austria</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Belgium</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Bosnia & Herzegovina</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Bulgaria</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Croatia</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Czech Republic</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Denmark</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Estonia</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Finland</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">France</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Germany</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Greece</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Hungary</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Italy</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Latvia</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Lithuania</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Luxembourg</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="nav-column">
                            <h3>mainland europe cont...</h3>
                            <ul>                                                                                                               
                                <li> <a href="#">Macedonia</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Montenegro</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Norway</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Poland</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Portugal</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Roménia</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Russia</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Serbia</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Slovakia</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Slovenia</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Spain</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Sweden</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Switzerland</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">The Netherlands</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Turkey</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Ukraine</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="nav-column">
                            <h3>north america</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#">Alaska</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Canada</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Mexico</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">United States</a> </li>
                            </ul>                     

                            <h3>central america</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#">Guatemala</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Costa Rica</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Cuba</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Panama</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">St Kitts and Nevis</a> </li>
                            </ul>                 

                            <h3>south america</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#">Argentina</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Brazil</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Bolívia</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Chile</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Colombia</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Ecuador</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Paraguay</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Peru</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Uruguay</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Venezuela</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="nav-column">
                            <h3>africa</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#">Egypt</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Morocco</a> </li>                                                        
                                <li> <a href="#">Namibia</a></li>                            
                                <li> <a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Tunisia</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Tanzania</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Zambia</a></li>
                            </ul>                        
                        </div>

                        <div class="nav-column">
                            <h3>asia</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#">Bangladesh</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Cambodia</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">China</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">India</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Indonesia</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Japan</a></li> 
                                <li> <a href="#">Laos</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Myanmar</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Nepal</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Singapore</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Thailand</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Tanzania</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Uzbekistan</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Vietnam</a> </li>

                            </ul>                                 

                            <h3>oceania</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#">Australia</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#">New Zealand</a> </li>                                                        

                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>   
                </li>

                <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
            </ul>         
        </div>


        <section id="galeria">
            <img class="slider fade" src="images/Flam Railway_small.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="slider fade" src="images/rocky-mountaineer.jpg" alt="" title="Rocky Mountaineer"/>
            <img class="slider fade" src="images/Hogwarts train.png" alt=""/>
            <img class="slider fade" src="images/amtrak-starlight_small.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="slider fade" src="images/hiram_bingham_720.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="slider fade" src="images/rovos rail.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="slider fade" src="images/Venice Simplon.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img class="slider fade" src="images/the ghan.jpg" alt=""/>

            <span id="prev">&laquo;</span>
            <span id="next">&raquo;</span>
        </section>      

        <section id="about">            

            <br>            
            <div id="aboutArticle">
                <h3>Discover the world's greatest train journeys</h3>                
                <p id="p1">                
                    Ever wondered where a train can take you, besides getting you to your workplace (if that's the case) ? <br><br>
                    There is another side of the story...across our beloved planet Earth, several trains meander through
                    viaducts, rivers, tunnels, glaciers and fjords, where beauty meets the eye. <br><br>
                    Several scenic train journeys can be found in every continent and that's what this site is all about...to showcase
                    every journey with a detailed description about it's points of interest, what to expect, what to see and guide
                    you through the magnificent views you will come across while looking through the window...<br><br> 

                    So, why not take a vacation in Switzerland and get on the Glacier Express? <br>
                    Or cross Asia in the Trans-Siberian train? <br>
                    Ever heard of the Blue train or the Rovos rail, two magnificent african journeys? <br>
                    Or even the Flam Railway in Norway?<br><br>

                    Get on board and discover what a scenic train journey can offer you...the possibility to travel
                    several miles, while watching the beautiful landscapes go by. <br><br>
                    There's no other form of transportation that can offer travelling through majestic, inaccessible places.
                    <br>                
                </p>            
            </div>            
        </section>

        <br>
        <br>

        <section id="contact">          
            <div id="contactForm">
                <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                <p>
                    If you wish to contact us about linking your site, copyright issues, feedback, errors on the website or any 
                    other issue, please send us a message using the form below.<br>
                    We appreciate your contact in helping us improve your navigation experience. 
                </p>

                <?php require_once 'form.php'; ?>
                <form id="form" name="contactForm" method="post" action="">
                    <div>
                        <label for="name">Your name</label> 
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="40" placeholder="Write your Name" value="<?php echo isset($name) ? $name : ''; ?>" >
                        <span class="error"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="email">Your email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="user_mail" placeholder="email@example.com" 
                               value="<?php echo isset($email) ? $email : ''; ?>">
                        <span class="error"><?php echo $emailError; ?></span> 
                    </div>                
                    <div>
                        <label for="topic">Select Topic</label>
                        <select id="topic" name="topic">
                            <option selected disabled hidden value="">Choose a Topic</option>
                            <option value="link">Site Link</option>
                            <option value="copyright"  
                            <?php echo isset($topic) ? ($topic == 'copyright' ? 'selected' : '') : ''; ?>
                                    >Copyright</option>
                            <option value="errors" 
                            <?php echo isset($topic) ? ($topic == 'errors' ? 'selected' : '') : ''; ?>
                                    >Site/Article errors</option>
                            <option value="feedback"
                            <?php echo isset($topic) ? ($topic == 'feedback' ? 'selected' : '') : ''; ?>
                                    >Feedback</option>
                            <option value="other"
                            <?php echo isset($topic) ? ($topic == 'other' ? 'selected' : '') : ''; ?>
                                    >Other</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="error"><?php echo $topicError; ?></span>
                    </div>                
                    <div>
                        <label for="msg">Your message</label>
                        <textarea id="msg" name="user_message" placeholder="Write your message"><?php echo isset($msg) ? $msg : ''; ?></textarea>
                        <span class="error"><?php echo $msgError; ?></span>
                    </div>                
                    <div class="button">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  value="true">Submit</button> 
                        <span class="success"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>            
        </section>

        <section id="footer">
            <p>
                O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria tipográfica e de impressão. 
                O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padrão usado por estas indústrias 
                desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de um texto para
                criar um espécime de livro. Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos,
                mas também o salto para a tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se
                essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização
                das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais
                recentemente com os programas de publicação como o Aldus PageMaker que
                incluem versões do Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </section>

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Arquivo **form.php**

```
<?php

$nameError = "";
$emailError = "";
$topicError = "";
$msgError = "";

if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) { // SE FOI POSTADO
    // só existem se foi postado
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['user_mail'];
    $topic = $_POST['topic'];
    $msg = $_POST['user_message'];

    if (empty($name) || !isset($name)) {
        $nameError = "Name is required";
    }

    if (empty($email) || !isset($email)) {
        $emailError = "Email is required";
    } elseif (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $emailError = "Please insert a correct email address";
    }

    if (empty($topic) || !isset($topic)) {
        $topicError = "Please choose a topic";
    }

    if (empty($msg) || !isset($msg)) {
        $msgError = "Let us know your opinion";
    }


    // só precisa conectar se foi postado
    $servername = "localhost:3306";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "site_comboios";
    //Create connection to database
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    //check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo 'Error connecting to database';
    }

    //Prepared Statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO contacts(Nome, Email, Topico,   Mensagem)  VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $name, $email, $topic, $msg);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

**Resultado:**
Print da tela com o resultado após postar o formulário:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Allan. Não é por ai pois eu já tinha colocado o form.php no atributo action do form. Entretanto testei a sua sugestão na mesma e acabei por ter erros de "undefined index" (as variáveis $name, $email, $topic e $msg não estão a chamar o respectivo atributo)

Comment: Já actualizei. Aguardo o resultado da sua simulação.

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta, espero que seja útil para ajudá-lo a resolver o seu problema. Boa sorte!

Comment: Caro @Allan . Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, assim consegui "saltar o muro". Entretanto só um à parte em relação à segurança dos dados...existe código php no index.php que estará visível para um possível atacante...dado que estou a inserir dados através de prepared statements, estarei com uma segurança elevada? Pergunto só para ter uma noção real deste tipo de problemas. Entretanto vou continuar com o resto do form já que ainda lhe faltam uns ajustes. Mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: Falar em segurança ELEVADA é muito relativo. Há relatos de empresas de segurança que pertencem a hackers famosos e que estas empresas foram hackeadas. No seu caso, acho que em termos de segurança está satisfatório.